# UMLDesigner – Diagram auto layout

Tags: uml-designer

I tried to use UMLDesigner to draw my project related diagrams. I see there is a Arrange functionality that can automatically layout diagram elements and links to save some manual work. But when i used it in my Activity diagrams it designed it upside down.

Here is an example. I created following [simple activity diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXMPG.png).
And here is how auto layout result for the same model looks like: [auto layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAJHq.png).

The initial node is at the bottom and the final nodes are on top. But i want it the other way - to start at the top and end at the bottom. Is there a way to configure this?

I tried pinning starting and final nodes but it just made a mess after arranging the rest automatically. I searched the settings but couldn't find anything. I use UML Designer Version  7.1.0.

Thanks ahead for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry there is no way from the preferences to change this behaviour.

This is because I never provide a specific layout for this diagram. Please, fill an issue in the bug tracker and it will be fixed for the next version of UML Designer as it is really easy to fix: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues.

Thanks for your feedback!